# Hierarchical Group Total

Tags: reporting-services, sum, ssrs-grouping

Could someone tell me how I could achieve the following?

```
Level                   Total
-------------------------------------
Top Level               $420
    Level 2a            $80
    Level 2b            $150
        Level 3ba       $50
        Level 3bb       $100
  Level 2c              $190
    Level 3ca           $30
    Level 3cb           $60
```

So Top Level contains the sales for all level 2 account and any sales which are applied directly to itself.

Level 2 contains level 3 sales below it, plus any sales which are applied to itself (see Level 2c for an example where $100 worth of sales have been applied).

I've tried using SUM and RunningValue and neither of them are actually giving me correct data.

The data is being grouped by AccountID and the parent is called ParentAccountID.  The RunningValue is `RunningValue(Fields!value_Sales.Value, SUM, "SalesData")`.  I've also tried `RunningValue(Fields!value_Sales.Value, SUM, "AccountID")` which is my primary group.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague managed to solve this:

=Sum(Fields!value_SALES.Value,"groupName",Recursive)